# Transitive subgroups of the symmetric group

Tags: number-theory, group-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct prime such that $p$ less than $q$. It is known that if $q-1$ not divisible by $p$, then every group of order $pq$ is a cyclic group. Thus suppose that $q-1$ is divisible by $p$ and $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $pq$. When $G$ will be a transitive subgroup of $S_q$? ($S_q$ is symmetric group of all permutation on $q$ symbols.)
In special case, put $p=2$ and $q$ an odd prime number, then the dihedral group of order $2q$, $D_q$, is a transitive subgroup of $S_q$.
Indeed I want to find that when such group $G$ as above, is Galois group of a number field?

Comment: A group $G$ of order $pq$ ($p,q$ distinct primes) has a unique subgroup of order $p$ up to conjugation (Sylow), and thus has a unique transitive action on a set of $q$ elements (up to isomorphism of $G$-set).

Answer (score 1):

There is only one non-abelian group of order $pq$ up to isomoprhism. It is given by semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ where the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ acts by mapping $1$ to a primitive root of unity of degree $p$ modulo $q$.

It can be embedded in $S_q$ through $AGL_1(\mathbb{F}_q)$ -- the group of automorphisms of affine line(it embeds into $\mathbb{F}_q$ via the action on $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$). Let $G\subset AGL_1(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be the group of transformations of the form $x\mapsto ax+b$ for $b\in\mathbb{F}_q,a\in C\subset \mathbb{F}_q^*$ where $C$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $p$. This group $G$ has order $pq$ and non-abelian, so is isomorphic to the group you are considering.